# Change 403 Error to 410 Error

Tags: centos, httpd

All 50+ pages are after *page2* `site.com/page1/page2/`.

How do I change the `403 Error` to `410 Error`?

```
403 Error

You are not authorized to access this page.

This might be because:

    The page is not published
    The page is part of the CMS
```

**1. Implement a custom 410 error page**

The 410 code indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again. This should be used when a job has been intentionally removed and the resource should be purged. Upon receiving a 410 status code, search engines should remove the resource from their index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RedirectMatch Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

```
RedirectMatch 410 <appropiate rule>
```

Update:

For a [custom error page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html), you can add:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /410error.html
```

An alternative method if you have many files is to use the following:

```
# Is the request for a non-existent file?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page1/page2/(.*) /page1/page2/$1 [R=410,L]
```

This is going to be used for all pages that are deleted or not exist in a particular directory. Be careful with this because overwrites the default behavior of 404 error

Comment: I used `Redirect 410 /page/page2`. This is now giving those sites: `The requested resource
/page/page2
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.`

Comment: @nicoX I updated the answer. The message you are reciving is a default for http code 410

Comment: Ok, so search engines should remove the resource from their index now. And if we want to add a custom page we include the `ErrorDocument`

Comment: I noticed that this approach needs to be changed. I though everything was deleted under`page2/`. Although there is another page connected with the pages in `page2/`. If I click on a page in `current/` it will redirect me to `page2/xxx`. So this pages are currently active, if I redirect `page2/` it will block access to these current pages. Now I don't know if I need to custom redirect all these 50+ pages?

Comment: Not only 50+, they are over 275 pages. I have them in an Excel spreadsheed, can I copy and paste them inside the .htaccess file?

Comment: @nicoX you can try with the second method. I just added in the answer

Comment: I'll will test this approach. What exactly do you mean overwrite the behaviour of _404 error_. There are five dead pages that generate _404_, but they as well will redirect to _410_. Is that concern for future _404_ pages?

Comment: @nicoX The problem can occur if the request is to a page that never existed on the server. For this case would be the right thing to error 404, but I think this approach is best suited to solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17918/discussion-between-nicox-and-federico-sierra).